# Получение text() при работе с элементами у которых общий родитель

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="booking">
    <div class="booking-date">
        <span>19 мая</span><br>
        понедельник
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">11:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">12:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">13:00</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

Добрый день, есть вот такой кусок кода. Никак не могу придумать как jquery мне выхватывать значение <span> при клике на любую из ссылок. Более того дат может быть несколько,  что вносит еще больший беспорядок в мой мозг так как для каждой кликнутой ссылке необходимо получать соответствующее ей значение span.
Догадываюсь что надо использовать parent(), но как его применить тут как-то не придумаю.
Может кто чего подсказать?

Comment: Да, именно, спасибо, никак не мог понять как к спану этому перейти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

HTML

```
<div class="booking">
    <div class="booking-date">
        <span>19 мая</span><br>
        понедельник
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">11:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">12:00</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">13:00</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $('ul li a').each(function(index,eleme){
        $(this).on('click',function(){
         var text = $('.booking-date span').text();
            alert(text);
        })   
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33jpM/

Comment: непонятно хачем вы приняли этот ответ, он неверный

http://jsfiddle.net/33jpM/1/

Comment: согласен, делал под конкретный пример

Comment: > Более того дат может быть несколько

Comment: было бы здорово, если бы Вы продемонстрировали пример на разные даты(если не сложно, так для общего развития)

Comment: ну я же ответ сделал, там неск вариантов. у вас ещё слишком заморочено хэндлер вешается, each там не нужен совсем.

Answer (score 4):

Это что-ли ?

```
$(this).parents('.booking').first().find('.booking-date span')
```

я там first добавил

ещё вариант, чтобы поменьше DOM копать:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.booking',function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('a')) return; //предполагаем, что нет других ссылок, кроме  нужных
        alert("text:" + $('span',this).text() + "\n" + "link:" + $(e.target).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s2pLL/